# jsoup how to extract this text

Tags: jsoup

*Update*

I'm trying to extract the "**Tweet Per Hour**" information from [here](http://www.twazzup.com/?q=mls&l=en). However, When I printed out the html from jsoup, I can't find that information anywhere.

Any tips?

<strike>I'm trying to extract the text "**105 TPH**" from the code below using jsoup.</strike>

```
<div id="speed_realtime" class="speed">
<a title="Tweets Per Hour">105 TPH</a>
</div
```

Will this be correct?

```
Element t = doc.select("a[title=Tweets Per Hour]").first();
tph = t.text();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, why ? isn't it working?

You could also do something like this:

```
Element tph = doc.select("#speed_realtime").select("a").first().text();
```

or

```
Element tph = doc.select("a[title]").first().text();
```

take a look at the docs for more options...

[Use selector-syntax to find elements](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)

[Use DOM methods to navigate a document](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation)

---

**EDIT**

try something like this

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.twazzup.com/?q=mls&l=en").userAgent("Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0)").get();
```

Comment: Hi! Thx alot for your help! I realise I was looking at the wrong place (updated above)!

Comment: Thx for your quick reply. Didn't make a difference though :(