# How to catch one specific text from html source code using Jsoup?

Tags: java, select, text, jsoup, element

I tried the solution from:

1. [How to extract text of paragraph from html using Jsoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17161243/how-to-extract-text-of-paragraph-from-html-using-jsoup)
2. [jsoup how to extract this text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154145/jsoup-how-to-extract-this-text)

but both examples are working with texts from tags.

I have this unique piece of code on my html web search:

[image]

and **what I need is to take the link that comes with the *d.href* variable.**

I tried codes like:

```
  Elements link = jSoupConnection.select(":contains(d.href)");  
  Elements link = jSoupConnection.select("#d.href");
  Elements link = jSoupConnection.getElementsByAttributeValueContaining("d.href","google");
```

but until now none of them worked.

I tried also to make one research at http://jsoup.org/cookbook/ and also nothing sucessfull. Could anyone more experienced with Jsoup help me please??
Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems that you are trying to parse JavaScript using JSoup.  This isn't possible using JSoup.  You'll need to parse it yourself.

Comment: actually I found one half solution a few minutes ago, I downloaded all the objects on the page which costs me 200mb in a txt file..now Im trying to limit this download size (which Im having one little bug) and in a few hours I will post or point the solution here =) Im just waiting to give one fully answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of your text doesn't come with any tag that you could specific catch with Jsoup select elements, you should download the hole page (which you can do with `Elements link = jSoupConnection.select("*");`) and then open it on your application as one text file to retrieve whatever you want. If the downloaded file is too big, and that was my problem, try to limit the file size download; more details you can find on those links:

1. [Limiting file size creation with java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17746114/limiting-file-size-creation-with-java/17747803#17747803)
2. [How to limit the file size in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089275/how-to-limit-the-file-size-in-java)